# Why is publishJUnitResults in the Azure pipelines Gradle task required and what it is used for?

Tags: azure, gradle, azure-devops

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops), parameter `publishJUnitResults` is required, but my pipeline works even without it. By my understanding of the documentation, by default, this is set to `true`, so there is probably no need to explicitly add this parameter anyway.

```
- task: Gradle@2
  name: BuildTestProject
  displayName: 'Build and Test Project'
  inputs:
     gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
     tasks: 'clean build'
     javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
     jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
```

Do you know, why it should be filled? I do not use this XML generated test report anywhere, so I am not sure if it is used somewhere by Azure internally.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we do not specify the `publishJUnitResults` parameter in the yaml pipeline, then the `publishJUnitResults` parameter defaults to `true`.

`publishJUnitResults`: Select this option to publish JUnit test results produced by the Gradle build to Azure Pipelines. Each test results file matching Test Results Files will be published as a test run in Azure Pipelines.

We can verify this in the classic pipeline. Check the "Publish to Azure Pipelines" option in the Gradle task, and then click `View Yaml`. We will find that the generated yaml does not contain the `publishJUnitResults` parameter.

[image]

[image]

[image]